# Flex: Access static constant from parent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, constants, parent-child

Why can't I treat a static constant defined in a parent class as a attribute of the child class in Flex?

### Flex

```c++
class A {
  public static const MAX:int = 100;
}

class B extends A {}

A.Max; // Valid
B.Max; // Invalid
```

### Java

```java
class A {
  public static final int MAX = 100;
}

class B extends A {}

A.Max; // Valid
B.Max; // Valid
```

Comment: [Great blog post on static functions with inheritance.](http://www.davidarno.org/2009/09/25/actionscript-3-inheritance-developers-beware/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick n' dirty hack:

In order to treat the constant `MAX` as a property of `B`, you must redefine `MAX` and set it equal to `A.MAX`:

```
class B extends A {
  public static const MAX:int = A.MAX;
}
```

---

## [Static properties not inherited](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=04_OO_Programming_11.html)

Static properties are not inherited by subclasses. This means that static properties cannot be accessed through an instance of a subclass. A static property can be accessed only through the class object on which it is defined. For example, the following code defines a base class named Base and a subclass that extends Base named Extender. A static variable named `test` is defined in the Base class. The code as written in the following excerpt does not compile in strict mode and generates a run-time error in standard mode.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class StaticExample extends MovieClip
    {
        public function StaticExample()
        {
            var myExt:Extender = new Extender();
            trace(myExt.test);// error
        }
    }
}

class Base {
    public static var test:String = "static";
}

class Extender extends Base { }
```

The only way to access the static variable `test` is through the class object, as shown in the following code:

```
Base.test;
```

It is permissible, however, to define an instance property using the same name as a static property. Such an instance property can be defined in the same class as the static property or in a subclass. For example, the Base class in the preceding example could have an instance property named `test`. The following code compiles and executes because the instance property is inherited by the Extender class. The code would also compile and execute if the definition of the test instance variable is moved, but not copied, to the Extender class.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class StaticExample extends MovieClip
    {
        public function StaticExample()
        {
            var myExt:Extender = new Extender();
            trace(myExt.test);// output: instance
        }
    }
}

class Base
{
    public static var test:String = "static";
    public var test:String = "instance";
}

class Extender extends Base {}
```

Comment: Interesting exercise. But, why?

Comment: Thought it was strange coming from a Java and C++ background.